# python looping fast through links

Tags: python, loops, python-requests

```
import requests
import json
from tqdm import tqdm
```

list of links to loop through

```
links =['https://www.google.com/','https://www.google.com/','https://www.google.com/']
```

for loop for the link using requests

```
data = []
for link in tqdm(range(len(links))):
    response = requests.get(links[link])
    response = response.json()
    data.append(response)
```

the above for loop is used to loop through all the list of links but its time consuming when I tried to loop on around a thousand links any help.

Comment: look into `async` and `aiohttp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to turn it multithreaded. Best way is probably asynchronous.

Multithreaded solution:

```
import requests
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import thread_map

links =['https://www.google.com/','https://www.google.com/','https://www.google.com/']

def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    response = response.json()  # Do note this might fail at times
    return response

data = thread_map(get_data, links)
```

Or without using `tqdm.contrib.concurrent.thread_map`:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tqdm import tqdm

links =['https://www.google.com/','https://www.google.com/','https://www.google.com/']

def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    response = response.json()  # Do note this might fail at times
    return response

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

data = list(tqdm(executor.map(get_data, links), total=len(links)))
```

Comment: dude please can you add a time.sleep() 
to sleep after every 2 links.

Comment: @yy.ch you're asking me to slow down the code?

Comment: yes but after two or more requests

Comment: Post a new question please, why are you trying to achieve that

Comment: I am looping on 5k links and most of the time it crashes after 1k requests, for this reason i want  it to sleep for a moment after every 800 requests

Comment: @yy.chazali post a new stackoverflow question with crash/traceback or any other information please :-)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment you can use **asyncio** and **aiohttp**.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

urls = ["your", "links", "here"]

# create aio connector
conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit_per_host=100, limit=0, ttl_dns_cache=300)

# set number of parallel requests - if you are requesting different domains you are likely to be able to set this higher, otherwise you may be rate limited
PARALLEL_REQUESTS = 10

# Create results array to collect results
results = []

async def gather_with_concurrency(n):
    # Create semaphore for async i/o  
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(n)

    # create an aiohttp session using the previous connector
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn)

    # await logic for get request
    async def get(URL):
        async with semaphore:
            async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
                obj = await response.read()
                # once object is acquired we append to list
                results.append(obj)
    # wait for all requests to be gathered and then close session
    await asyncio.gather(*(get(url) for url in urls))
    await session.close()

# get async event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# run using number of parallel requests
loop.run_until_complete(gather_with_concurrency(PARALLEL_REQUESTS))
# Close connection
conn.close()

# loop through results and do something to them
for res in results:
    do_something(res)
```

I have tried to comment on the code as well as possible.

I have used BS4 to parse requests in this manner (in the `do_something` logic), but it will really depend on your use case.

Comment: i tried serveral times to use it but i get much errors in returns. but its so helpful and i am working to understand it. thank you

Comment: Maybe if you share the errors I can help?

Comment: ~/downloads $ python connect.py
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/downloads/connect.py:96: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/downloads/connect.py", line 98, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(gather_with_concurrency(PARALLEL_REQUESTS))
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()

Comment: File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/downloads/connect.py", line 92, in gather_with_concurrency
    await asyncio.gather(*(get(url) for url in urls))
NameError: name 'urls' is not defined
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0xf3e49cb8>

Comment: this is what i have been strugling with

Comment: Ah, apologies there was an error in my code. I have edited the answer so it should now work.

Comment: thanks for the effort bro, its so helpful